# Java NullReferenceException when using interface

Tags: java, spring, interface, nullpointerexception

I have a Spring REST API I am developing that keeps returning a NullReferenceException for some reason. I can't figure out why. Here is my code:

The interface:

```
public interface InitiativesService {
    InitiativeDto createInitiative(InitiativeDto initiativeDto);    
}
```

The class that implements it:

```
public class InitiativeServiceImpl implements InitiativesService {

    private final InitiativeRepository initiativeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public InitiativeServiceImpl(InitiativeRepository initiativeRepository)
    {
        this.initiativeRepository = initiativeRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public InitiativeDto createInitiative(InitiativeDto initiativeDto) {
        initiativeRepository.Save(initiativeDto);
    }
```

The Repository class for communicating to the dB:

```
@Repository
public interface InitiativeRepository extends JpaRepository<Initiative, Long> {}
```

And lastly the controller:

```
public class InitiativesController {

  private InitiativesService initiativesService;
  
  public InitiativesController(InitiativesService initiativesService) {
    this.initiativesService = initiativesService;
  }

  @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<InitiativeDto> createInitiative(@Valid @RequestBody InitiativeDto initiative) {


    log.info("Saving");
    InitiativeDto createdInitiative = initiativesService.createInitiative(initiative);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdInitiative);
  }
```

When I try running this and testing via Postman, it returns a NullPointerException. I debug it and I can see the initiativesService is null. I am confused as I have the same implementation for creating Users which works fine without this issue. Can anyone spot any problems I have here?

Comment: Which is it? `NullReferenceException` or `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Autowired` annotation on your constructor to autowire your `initiativeService`

```
@Autowired
public InitiativesController(InitiativesService initiativesService) {
    this.initiativesService = initiativesService;
}
```

Comment: This should not be needed since Spring 4.x . It automatically autowires the constructor.

Comment: oh shoot really? I never knew that before. all my life i have been autowiring my services through my constructor using the `@Autowired` annotation

Comment: @DonatoAmasa it works now, thank you. I can see its on the other controller but didn't realise it wasn't here. Suspected it would be something small like this.

Comment: @DonatoAmasa Yeah! Here's the Spring 4.3 blog post for this feature: https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3

Comment: Sure thing @Yohan! Alright thanks @Benjamin M for the link.